# Image upload script more cleaner and secure using php 7 oop style.

Tags: php

I want to utilize namespaces and make the code on this file uploading script more secure, and cleaner looking, here is what i have so far

it uploads an image and inserts it into a database.

I want to be able to use namespaces within view files, without it looking messy.

i know i can use laravel blade etc, but for the sake of sharpening my php skills, i want to be able to do this from scratch.

**Image.php**

```
<?php

require 'Db.php';


class Image{

    private $dbh;
    private $connect;
    public $directory;
    public $uploadfile;




    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbh = new Db();
        $this->connect =  $this->dbh->connect();
        $this->directory = "uploads/";
    }


    public function upload_image($filename, $image_name)
    {

        $this->uploadfile = $this->directory . basename($filename);

        try{
            $stmt = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO images (img, image_name) VALUES (:img, :imagename) ");
            $stmt->bindparam(':img', $this->uploadfile);
            $stmt->bindparam(':imagename', $image_name);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt; 
        }
        catch(PDOExeception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


    }

    public function get_image()
    {
        return $this->uploadfile;
    }

}
```

**upload_image.php (view file)**

```
    <form action="/ImgUpload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
            <input type="file" name="profile_img" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
            <input type="text" name="image_name" placeholder="Enter Name Of File" class="mt-3">
            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is some placeholder block-level help text for the above input. It's a bit lighter and easily wraps to a new line.</small>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>

        </form>
```

**ImgUpload.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Image.php';



if(isset($_FILES['profile_img'])){

    $image = new Image();

    $filename = $_FILES["profile_img"]["name"];
    $realname = "uploads/" . basename($filename);
    $directory = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eliphp1/uploads/";

    $path = $directory . basename($filename);

    $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];


    if($image->upload_image($realname, $image_name)){

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_img"]["tmp_name"], $path);

        echo '<img src="'.$image->get_image().'">';


    };


};




?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on the answer from Stexxe...

> it can have connection to database ($this->connect of your Image class) as dependency

A database class is different from all other classes. It cannot be created any time on demand. It has to be created only once, connect to a database, and hold this connection all the time. Otherwise numerous connections from the same script will crash your database server.

So it has to be:

```
class ImageMapper{

    private $connect;

    public function __construct($connect)
    {
        $this->connect = $connect;
    }
```

and called like this:

```
$dbh = new Db();
$connect =  $dbh->connect();

$image = new Image($connect);
```

> manipulation images classes should not expose any information about their inner workings

Among other things, it means that error reporting should never reveal the actual error to a site user. Therefore you should never ever do anything like `die($error)` -- which also makes the whole `try..catch` business misplaced in this code.  So it should be:

```
public function upload_image($filename, $image_name)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (img, image_name) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $this->connect->prepare($sql)->execute([$filename, $image_name]);
}
```

whereas a possible exception thrown by PDO must be caught elsewhere. Learn more from my article on [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

Some other stuff has also been fixed, mostly your extremely confusing way assigning a filename, when you are adding, removing and re-adding the directory name. Some useless variables like `$directory` and `$filename` are also removed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to separate responsibility to following classes:

- `Image` Basically value object to store image's state (temporary path to uploaded image and actual path or any other information about image)
- `ImageUploader` The only one responsibility of this class is to move uploaded file to new place and change image's state after. I think this class could be static.
- `ImageStore` Class for storing image in a database. it can have connection to database (`$this->connect` of your `Image` class) as dependency. It should only be responsible to store data about image in a database.

Also, manipulation images classes should not expose any information about their inner workings (how image data is actually stored or how works image uploading)

**Pseudo code for ImgUpload.php**

```
Get information about image from POST
Create image object
Create store for images
Save Image to store
Upload image
```