# Upload image using php 7 best practices to make it secure

Tags: php

I have a script that uploads an image, inserts it into database,  and displays it on the home page.

However it's not secure, how can i make this script more secure and make sure it allows only jpeg/jpg files.

**UploadController.php**

```
public function upload_image($filename, $image_name)
{

    $this->uploadfile = $this->directory . basename($filename);

    try{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (img, image_name) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)->execute([$filename, $image_name]);
        return $stmt; 
    }
    catch(PDOExeception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

**Home.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'paritals/header.php';
require_once 'paritals/nav.php';


use Eli\Db as DB;
use ElCont\UploadController as Image;


    if(isset($_FILES['profile_img'])){

        $dbh = new DB();
        $connect = $dbh->connect();
        $image = new Image($connect);

        $filename = $_FILES["profile_img"]["name"];
        $realname = "public/uploads/" . basename($filename);
        $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/public/uploads/";

        $path = $directory . basename($filename);

        $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];


        if($image->upload_image($realname, $image_name)){

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_img"]["tmp_name"], $path);

            $owl = $image->get_image();


        }

}?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4 p-5 ">
            <h1>Upload Image</h1>
            <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" name="profile_img" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                    <input type="text" name="image_name" placeholder="Enter Name Of File" class="mt-3">
                    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is some placeholder block-level help text for the above input. It's a bit lighter and easily wraps to a new line.</small>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row p-5">
<?php

$dbh = new DB();
$connect = $dbh->connect();
$image = new Image($connect);

$photo =  $image->get_images();
foreach($photo as $pic)

{?>


            <div class="col-md-4">
              <h1><?php echo $pic['image_name'];?></h1>
                <img src="<?php echo $pic['img'];?>" width="300" height="400">

            </div>


<?php }?>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php require_once  'paritals/footer.php';?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you aren't following suggestions have been given to you in the [other post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196538/image-upload-script-more-cleaner-and-secure-using-php-7-oop-style). So again:

One of insecurities is revealing the internal error message to a site user. [Remove that try and catch stuff](https://phpdelusions.net/top#try_catch) from the database interaction and configure your server to report errors appropriately like you've been told.

Same goes for adding directory to the file name. **Please remember, you already added it in the step before:**

```
$realname = "uploads/" . basename($filename);
```

therefore, the following code makes no sense:

```
$this->uploadfile = $this->directory . basename($filename);
```

Do you realize that?
Besides, a function responsible for storing a filename in the database should be dong only that - storing a filename. Assigning the filename or error reporting should be done elsewhere.

It means your upload image method should be exactly like this:

```
public function store($filename, $image_name)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (img, image_name) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $this->connect->prepare($sql)->execute([$filename, $image_name]);
}
```

making it to do the only stuff it is intended for.

Regarding security, the main point is to verify the file's extension. Your web-server will judge the file type by its extension so should you.

```
$allowed = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
    // process your file
} else {
    // tell a user the extension is not allowed
}
```

regarding general purpose best practices. Looks like your namespaces are inconsistent. It seems you want something like that

```
use Eli\Db as DB;
use Eli\Controller\UploadController as Image;
```

and also you are supposed to implement [PSR-4 autoload](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) so you won't have to include class definitions manually

Comment: thank you common sense, i need to be paying better attention sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle uploads is to use open source, well designed and tested libraries such as [Upload](https://github.com/brandonsavage/Upload). But if you want to do it yourself you can use methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/how-to-check-uploaded-file-type-in-php)